# Импорт внешних скриптов из бандла JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack4

Возможно ли импортирование внешних скриптов из уже скомпилированного бандла через webpack.

Имеется проект с функционалом скелета на js.
К нему требуется писать много различных расширений и дополнений (однотипных), хотелось бы из основного файла бандла динамически импортировать эти скрипты внутрь для использования, но после добавления не пересобирать сборку, а просто подключать, загружать с сервера.

Comment: Выноси общие скрипты в npm-пакет

Comment: дело в том что расширение уже компилировано тем же самым webpack как отдельное существо. Не хотелось бы его собирать в общий файл с проектом.